# How to re-arrange nested promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript promise methods. I have a html page from which I need to make several api calls using javascript. The api calls should be done one after the other (only when one api call is successful go to next api call etc).

I tried to use javascript promise in chain (pseudo code below) which is working.

```
function getalldata()
{
    //few lines of code before 1st api call
    APImethod1.then{
    //few lines of code after 1st api call
    }
    .then{
            /few lines of code before 2nd api call
            APImethod1.then{
            //few lines of code after 2nd api call
            }
        }
        .then{
                /few lines of code before 3rd api call
                APImethod1.then{
                //few lines of code after 3rd api call
                }
            }
            .then{
                    /few lines of code before 4th api call
                    APImethod1.then{
                    //few lines of code after 4th api call
                    }
                //and so on         
                }   
}
```

But the nested code looks messy as i have to make a several api calls and the code blocks are more. So I wanted to keep each api call into a separate promise and at the end call the promise in the sequence i wanted. something like below.

```
 function callAPImethods() {
            var promise1 = new Promise(function (Resolve, Reject) {
                console.log("promise1")
                Resolve("test1success");
            });
            var promise2 = new Promise(function (Resolve, Reject) {
                console.log("promise2")
                Resolve("test2success");
            });
            var promise3 = new Promise(function (Resolve, Reject) {
                console.log("promise3")
                Resolve("test3success");
            });

            console.log("start");
            promise1.then(
                function (value) {
                    promise2.then(function (value) {
                        promise3.then(function (value) {
                            console.log("end");
                        })
                    })
                })
        }
```

the above code seems to execute the promise block first before they are called at the bottom. the console output is
promise1
promise2
promise3
start

I want the code block in promise to be executed only when called at the end of the function. Basically the console output i want is below. Thanks in advance.
start
promise1
promise2
promise3
end

Comment: Your first code isn't valid syntax. `then` is a function, it needs parentheses after it, not curly braces.

Comment: What are `test1`, `test2`, and `test3`? Shouldn't those be `promise1, promise2, promise3`?

Comment: Yes, sorry pseudo code should be promise1,promise2,promise3 as you pointed out. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try async/await. Below is the example for await and async.

The following script wait for second promise (2 Seconds) to complete (Because i added `setTimeout(r, 2000);` in second promise).

```js
async function callAPImethods() {
    var promise1 = await new Promise(function(Resolve, Reject) {
        console.log("promise1")
        Resolve("test1success");
    });
    var pm = await new Promise(r => {
        setTimeout(r, 2000);
        console.log(456)
    });
    var promise2 = await new Promise(function(Resolve, Reject) {

        console.log("promise2")
        Resolve("test2success");
    });
   //REMAINING CODES HERE
}
 callAPImethods()
```

The following script not wait for second promise to complete.

```js
async function callAPImethods() {
      var promise1 = await new Promise(function(Resolve, Reject) {
          console.log("promise1")
          Resolve("test1success");
      });
      var pm = new Promise(r => {
          setTimeout(r, 2000);
          console.log(456)
      });
      var promise2 = await new Promise(function(Resolve, Reject) {
          console.log("promise2")
          Resolve("test2success");
      });
      //ADD REMAINING CODES HERE
  }
callAPImethods()
```

Comment: Thanks, This implementation worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

`new Promise(your_executor_function)` calls `your_executor_function` **immediately**.

That is how promises work.

Calling the `then()` method on a promise determines what happens when the promise is finished.

It does not trigger `your_executor_function` (which is trigged when you **create** the promise).

---

If you want to arrange some complex code to run later: Put it (i.e. the whole `new Promise(...)` code) in **a function**, then call that function when you need it.

---

You might also want to look at [the `async`/`await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) which saves having a sequence of nested `then` calls.